# L'expression « faire recours » : est-ce légitime d'y avoir recours ?

Tags: sens, locutions, auxiliaires

Je remarque que « *faire recours à* » concurrence de plus en plus la locution verbale « *avoir recours à* ». Cette tendance est [récente et reste minoritaire](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir+recours%2Cfaire+recours%2Cavoir+recours+à%2Cfaire+recours+à&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19) (en tout cas sur le papier). Seule la deuxième forme est relevée par [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recours//1), [le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_recours), ou même [le Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/recours/67165/locution?q=recours#166030).

L'emploi de *faire recours* se justifie-t-il ? dans quels cas ?

À supposer qu'il y en ait une, comment expliquer la différence d'usage qui distingue ces deux tournures ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curieusement la première forme est bien présente dans le TLF dans l'exemple de la définition C.1. De ce que j'ai pu lire, on devrait dire **introduire un recours devant…**. J'ai pu lire ça sur le [site web de la Cour nationale du droit d'asile](http://www.cnda.fr/comment-introduire-un-recours/) (CDNA). Mais ils ont également une section *Quand faire un recours*, ce qui m'amène à penser que cette formulation s'utilise quand on ne souhaite pas préciser les circonstances du recours. Faire recours semble donc une forme réduite.

La formulation **avoir recours à** s'utilise de manière plus générale. Mais je ne pense pas que **faire recours à** soit correct en français, sûrement un mélange de *faire recours*, *avoir recours à* et *faire appel à*…

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai rien vu dans mes références habituelles qu'une absence de mentions pour « faire recours ».

Quasiment toutes les occurrences de « faire recours » trouvées par Google me choquent. Cela me me choque le moins quand il s'agit de « faire recours à une personne » plutôt qu'à une chose ou à un moyen ; je ne dirais d'ailleurs pas « j'ai recours à mon voisin pour ... » mais « j'ai recours à l'aide de mon voisin pour ... »

À noter que j'ai vu des occurrences de « faire recours à », dont le sens était « effectuer un recours contre [une décision administrative] » ce qui me choque encore plus, pas tant le « faire recours » mais l'utilisation de « à » pour introduire parfois l'institution auprès de laquelle le recours est déposé, parfois même la décision contre laquelle le recours est déposé.

Comment: Quid de celles trouvées [ici](http://www.lemonde.fr/recherche/?keywords=%22faire+recours%22&qt=recherche_globale) ou [là](http://recherche.lefigaro.fr/recherche/recherche.php?ecrivez=%22faire+recours%22), etc. ? Certaines ne sont pas de simples accidents syntaxiques.

Comment: Je n'ai regardé qu'une partie (et n'étant pas abonné je n'ai pas trouvé le contexte complet pour certains). Le seul « faire recours à » dans le sens qui t'intéresse me choque.  Il y a principalement des « faire recours » qui concernent l'opposition à des décisions administratives ou judiciaires qui ne me choquent pas réellement, n'étant pas suivis de « à ».

Comment: Ok j'avais mal compris le sens de ta dernière phrase alors :-)

Comment: Tiens, le Figaro a en effet un « faire recours à la Cours européenne des droits de l'homme » qui lui me choque bien (j'aurais mis « déposer un recours auprès ... »)